# How to get device descriptor using WebUSB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, usb, webusb

I use Wireshark on usbmon3 to to analyze the packets to and from the USB.
So when I plug in my device, Wireshark shows me what is being sent, and what is being received.

**Sent**: [image: Sending description request of USB device]

**Received:** [image]

I'm trying pretty much to do the same but using Webusb. Here's my code in javascript:

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x0403 }] })
    .then(selectedDevice => {
        device = selectedDevice;
        return device.open(); // Begin a session.
    })
    .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1)) // Select configuration #1 for the device.
    .then(() => device.claimInterface(0)) // Request exclusive control over interface #0.
    .then(() => device.controlTransferOut({
        requestType: 'standard',
        recipient: 'device',
        request: 0x06,
        value: 0x00,
        index: 0x00}))
    .then(() => device.transferIn(1, 64))
    .then(result => {
        let decoder = new TextDecoder();
        console.log('Received: ' + decoder.decode(result.data));
    })
    .catch(error => {
         console.log(error); 
    });
```

What I get back in my console log is this: [image: Received nothing] Which i assume is completely nothing.

Ofcourse I know that if i just `console.log(device)` I will receive the device description in my console. But I'm trying to understand the function itself mainly to know what should go into the `requestType, recipient, request, value, index` fields by sending the same `GET DESCRIPTOR (0x06)` command (Like the first picture) and receiving back the device description in the `console.log('Received: ' + decoder.decode(result.data));` section. The reason I'm trying to do something as simple as that is because I'll be doing more transfers along other devices connected to this USB device in particular, so I need to understand what to send within those parameters.

After I use the function, I check back on Wireshark to see why I dont get anything back and I get this: [image]

I'm assuming the `Broken pipe (-EPIPE) (-32)` is the reason behind me not receiving anything back. I don't know where I'm doing wrong and I'm completely lost.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't quite reproducing the request you see in Wireshark. To do that you need,

```js
device.controlTransferIn({
    requestType: 'standard',
    recipient: 'device',
    request: 0x06,
    value: 0x0100,
    index: 0x0000}, 255)).then(result => {
  // Parse the device descriptor from result.data.
});
```

For a GET_DESCRIPTOR request the first byte of `value` is the descriptor type and the second byte is the descriptor index. This is documented in the USB specifications you can download from [usb.org](https://usb.org/):

[image: Screenshot of section 9.4.3 from the USB 1.1 specification]

The `transferIn()` call you make is not necessary. The result of the control transfer is provided in `result`. Calling `transferIn()` will initiate a new transfer on the specified endpoint.

The data returned by the descriptor request is not text so you won't be able to parse it using a TextDecoder. `result.data` is a `DataView` which has convenient methods for reading various sized values from any index. The structure of a device descriptor is also included in the specifications:

[image: Screenshot of table 9-7 from the USB 1.1 specification]
[image: Screenshot of table 9-7 (continued) from the USB 1.1 specification]

Comment: One last question, hope you don't mind. If I want to send in, for example: "RQ_GETDEVID” (8bits CRC for "RQ_GETDEVID” is equal to 0x66), I would need to put the 0x66 at the 'request' parameter, is that correct ?

Comment: That seems correct. If you want to ask a question about communicating with a particular device please include information about the device and links to any documentation you have found.

Comment: I just noticed when i plug in the device, Wireshark would show me that the endpoint is 'IN'. But when i run the code the endpoint is 'OUT'. I tried to use controlTransferIn instead, I don't get the 'stall' information i usually get now, but the endpoint it is sending to is still 0x00 'OUT' instead of 0x80 'IN'

Comment: The control endpoint is neither in nor out. It can be used for both depending on the request being made.